# How to create an side paragraph in HTML alongside an image?

Tags: html, css

I have image I would like to display in HTML alongside an paragraph, with some information. Essentially, I need the page to have the image on one side of the page and the paragraph on the other. Does a grid need to be use? Is There another way to do this without a grid.

I would suspect that if I do not put a `<br>` after `<img>` tag that it will just align itself to  the right.

Is there some CSS involved to do this?

Comment: "I suspect". Why don't you try it and see what happens? Then try some different CSS out, based on research you've done? Stack Overflow isn't really here to write all of your code for you (although plenty of people may do just that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `float` and `display` CSS properties needed !

```css
img , p {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
}
p {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png">
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: No need for the `float: right` on the `<p>` tag, that forces right aligned. Simple padding and margins would do on each element\.

Comment: @Illdapt you are right! but he says "I need the page to have the image on one side of the page and the paragraph on the other. "

Comment: Yes exactly, not right aligned. I don't know of any good designer that would right align text elements. I'm sure hes thinking "like a book"

Comment: Thanks, was able to get this work, just need to learn how to do this with ids for <img> and <p> elements.

Comment: @JDavila it will be very helpful if you make jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3):

The other way to accomplish this (other than the way Sohaib put) is to simply just have both elements be floated to the left or to the right. Margin added to help move the text.

```css
img,
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
}
p {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png">
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Cool! but he says "I need the page to have the image on one side of the page and the paragraph on the other. "

Comment: I did not notice that. Then Definitely @SohaibMohammed 's way is preferred.